# Is it bad practice to to use wrapping anonymous function for module.exports in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've started to use wrapping anonymous function in my NodeJS express modules lately as it somehow helps me write cleaner code.

However I'm not sure if this is considered bad/good practice in the Node environment (maybe some debugging/optimization issues?), it is extensively used by Coffeescript so I guess it must be OK, is it?

*Express Controller example:*

```
module.exports = (function() {

  function LinksController() {}

  var moment = require('moment'),
      _ = require('underscore'),
      Q = require('q');

  LinksController.edit = function edit(req, res, next) {
        ...
  }

  return LinksController;

})();
```

Comment: interesting, isnt the js file basically wrapped in a `(function(){ ` ... `})();` anyway?

Comment: I don't know if it's necessarily bad practice, but it's certainly not *necessary* here. Generally, an inner object-building function is used to create a closure for "private" functions that shouldn't be accessible from the global scope, but your scripts inside an `require`-imported script don't attach variables to the global scope anyway, I believe.

Comment: Coffee Script uses a similar approach in part because this is **necessary** for client-side JavaScript to prevent polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing technically wrong with doing this, but it's completely unnecessary.